# css width of 2 divs in percentage with min width of one div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I have 2 div elements in a wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="widgets" class="sidebar-left"></div>
    <div id="content" class="content-right"></div>
</div>
```

I have to say that I use the wordpress responsive Theme and the two inner div elements appear one floating left `sidebar-left` and the oder floating `content-right` right.

This is the sample .css code:

[image]

With this code they always have the same percentage of horizontal width when you make your browser window smaller.

This whole process starts with the `@media (min-width: 650px)`

I want that the `sidbar-left` keeps his 14% width from the initial 650px and only the `content-right` adjusts to the reduction of the browser window.

Because I use the Wordpress "responsive" Theme it only works so far it hte width of both elements gets 14% + 82%, so I need something that makes the width of the `content-right` smaller if you decrease your browser window size.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `sidebar-left` inside the `@media (min-width: 650px)` and the `content.right` outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

So you need a fixed width sidebar-left and a fluid width content-right, right?

```
.sidebar-left {
    width: 91px; /* 14% of 650px */
    float:left;
}
.content-right {
    margin-left: 101px; /* leave 10px space */
}
```